# JAVA :Unable to view println after the while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm unable to view the println after exiting the "For" and "While" loop. 
What am i doing wrong?

Assignment is : to Extract doubles from a txt file that has the numbers split by a "," . once i have the data do some calculations and display it. I've done all except the displaying. which I'm having some difficulty in.

```
            try {


                FileInputStream ofile = new FileInputStream("Sales Analysis.txt"); 
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(ofile);
                BufferedReader Rreader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in));
                String Filedata ;
                String read;
                double[] TotalWeekSales = new double [7];
                double[] DailyAverage = new double [7];
                double TotalSales = 0;
                double[] amount= new double [7];
                double AverageSales = 0;
                int Topsale = -1 ; // Position of Highest Week Sale
                int LowestSale= -1;  // Lowest Week Sale



                while ((Filedata= Rreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] Splitt = Filedata.split(",");
                    //double amount[] =new double [10];

                    for (int i = 0; i<Filedata.length(); i++)
                    {

                        read = Splitt[i];
                        amount[i] = Double.parseDouble(read);
                        TotalWeekSales[i] = amount[i];
                        DailyAverage[i]= (amount[i]/7);
                        TotalSales +=  amount[i];




                    System.out.println("\nWeek: "+(i+1));
                        System.out.println("\nAmount : $"+amount[i]);

                    }

                };

     /********* This part below doesn't Print ***********/

                AverageSales = (TotalSales/7);
                System.out.println("\nTotal Average Sales: $"+AverageSales); 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            }

    }
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly relevant to your question, and I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit. I hope it looks a bit more relevant to my question. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i<Filedata.length(); i++)`

should be:

`for (int i = 0; i < Splitt.length; i++)`

there might be other bugs as well.

Note: it's difficult to read the code since it's not indented properly.